# php codeigniter email library

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

i'm having a trouble here.
why can't i send email using smtp?
the error looks like this.
[image: email bug]

the code looks like this

```
   $config = Array(
                    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'mail.email.com',
                    'smtp_port' => 25,
                    'smtp_user' => 'admin@email.com',
                    'smtp_pass' => 'pass'
                    );
            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->cc('admin@provider.net');
            $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
            $this->email->from('admin@provider.net', 'Admin');

$this->email->send();
if(!$this->email->send())
{
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

---

code update:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config = Array(
                      'protocol' => 'smtp',
                      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                      'smtp_port' => 465,
                      'smtp_user' => 'account@gmail.com',
                      'smtp_pass' => 'password',
                      'smtp_timeout' => '4',
                      'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                      'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
                );
                $this->email->initialize($config);
                $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                //$this->email->set_mailtype('html');
                $this->email->cc('admin@email.co.id');
                $this->email->from('admin@email.co.id', 'Admin');
                $this->email->to('email@email.com');
                $this->email->subject('test online');
                $this->email->message('test email');
                if(!$this->email->send())
                {
                    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'sent';
                }
```

and it returned this message.

**Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**

Comment: are u trying it on localhost?

Comment: no, on the web server, i have no problem on localhost

Comment: try adding this on the config `$config['_smtp_auth']  = TRUE;`

Comment: @tomexsans still no difference,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! 
the problem was not the openSSL or the script,
the problem was SELinux forbid httpd to send mail
and the solution was **setsebool httpd_can_sendmail on**

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the smtp_port parameter '465' in quotes and change the from to the same address as the account you are using to send the mail.

Comment: sorry this is already fixed, the main problem is SELINUX and it's fixed by doing setsebool httpd_can_sendmail on

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'admin@email.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'pass';

$this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->cc('admin@provider.net');
            $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
            $this->email->from('admin@provider.net', 'Admin');

$this->email->send();
if(!$this->email->send())
{
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

try this....may this help....

Comment: do i have to use gmail account?

Comment: if you are trying to do this on localhost you have to add access from gmail for less security apps `https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps`